# How to get a datetime interval as seconds (int)?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, intervals

I have a table containing some datetime columns, now I want to get the timespan/interval between two columns in seconds (as int):

```
declare @Sessions TABLE
(
  [session_id] [int] not null,
  [start] [datetime] not null,
  [end] [datetime] not null
)
insert into @Sessions([session_id], [start], [end])
values (1, '01.04.2012 08:15:05', '01.04.2012 08:16:40');

select [session_id], [end]-[start] as 'duration'
from @Sessions
```

What I get is a datetime like interval type: eg. 1900-01-01 00:01:35.000.
What I want is the timespan in seconds: eg. 95s.

Parsing the String should not be an option as I suppose that there's an easy to use function for that - deeply hidden in the msdn documentation, which I haven't found yet.
So, how to get those time intervals as int in seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change last select as

```
select [session_id],datediff(ss,[start],[end]) as 'duration' from @Sessions
```

I have tried the same below using table instead of table variable:

[image]

Comment: I use a table as well, but posted it as variable to provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Answer (score 1):

Using [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), you can get the difference between 2 dates down to whichever resolution you want

e.g.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, start, end)
FROM @Sessions
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  [session_id]
      , DATEDIFF(second, [start] - [end]) as 'Duration'
FROM @Sessions
```

[DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.